# How increases the flow rate of a fluid by increasing pipe diameter?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Can I increase flow rate of a fluid by increasing pipe diameter for a transfer line? If so, how do I calculate it?

Comment: what are you trying to calculate?  The flow? The diameter? Some other property of the material (not water)?  Are you restricted to fluids and if yes how different and in what way different from water should your fluid be?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I think the OP thinks in fluids. He wants to know, how changes the flow rate with the increased pipe diameter. This question is clear to me.

Comment: @peterh you could be right... why the "not water"?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes. Maybe the question could be edited to remove this.

Comment: @nikkimarie I think it doesn't really matter if the fluid is water or not. I edited the water part out of your question, is it so okay?

Comment: @peterh hopefully you edit still captures the essence of the original question...

Comment: Is the imposed pressure drop the same in both cases?

Comment: Refer Moody's chart.